# Remove seconds from TimeSpan EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am creating a view containing a form in ASP.NET MVC3 for a model containing time spans. I was wondering if there is a way that I can prevent the text box that is rendered from showing the seconds part? So that instead of `12:30:00` , I would get `12:30`?

Here is what I have in the model and view:

```
//model
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }


//view
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
    </div>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
public TimeSpan Start { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ok, this is the same solution that i have followed, but does not work! @Tom: you work?

Comment: @Alberto Rubini, you probably missed something. Though to say especially when your problem description is `but does not work`.

Comment: in my EditorFor control (in a view) the value is 12:30:00 when i expect 12:30. I try with @"0:HH\:mm",  @"0:hh:mm" but doesn't work!! the only different is that my property is TimeSpan? (nullable)

Comment: @Alberto Rubini, are you using the `EditorFor` helper or inside your editor template you used the `TextBoxFor` helper?

Comment: As Alberto has discovered, this doesn't work across all browsers.  Will display formatted in IE but ignored in Chrome.

Comment: I use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start) but this generates a runtime error 
`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.TimeSpan', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.`
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Darin works but the validation still not work like I would expect. I added a custom validation. That custom validation is doing a regular expression without a regular expression attribute. This is done otherwise you can't post times like 14:30 because the regular expression will stop it or the TimeSpan object will stop it because it expects a TimeSpan like 00:00:00.

So I created this validation for MVC 5 with Entity Framework 6 in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

```
public class Training : IValidatableObject
{
    private const string Time = @"^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:00$";

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Starttime")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Endtime")]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm}")]
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        Regex timeRegex = new Regex(Time);

        if (!timeRegex.IsMatch(StartTime.ToString()))
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Starttime is not a valid time hh:mm", new[] { "StartTime" }));
        }

        if (!timeRegex.IsMatch(EndTime.ToString()))
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("Endtime is not a valid time hh:mm", new[] { "EndTime" }));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```